# Unexisted values in database table after manually changed values in browser source code

Tags: php, database, security, mysqli, insert-into

I have a form with 2 select elements.
- Select 1 with 5 countries from DB table 'landen',
- Select 2 with 15 dishes from DB table 'gerechten'.
Select 2 is dependent on select 1. (I use AJAX for this)
After submit it will insert into table 3  with the chosen selections.

Dishes 1, 2 & 3 belongs to country 1, dishes 4, 5, & 6 belongs to country 2, etc.

I use MySQLi Object Orientated to connect with the database.

The two select queries and the insert query work well. I see the selections in the 3rd table.

**Dutch - English**
landen - countries
gerechten - dishes

In the 3rd database table landGerecht the columns are:
- landGerecht_id, (auto increment)
- land_id,
- gerecht_id,
- created_at (Current Timestamp)

*My code in the insert file insertKeuze.php:*

```
<?php
$landKeuze = $_POST['landen'];
$gerechtKeuze = $_POST['gerechten'];

if (!empty($landKeuze) && !empty($gerechtKeuze)) {
   // Insert statement with placeholders for the values to database table landGerecht
   $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO `lab_stage_danush` . `landGerecht` (`land_id`, `gerecht_id`) VALUES ( ?, ?)";

      // If query is prepared then bind $landKeuze with land_id and $gerechtKeuze with gerecht_id and execute the query.
      if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($queryInsert)) {
         // Protect and validate land against hacking
         $landKeuze = hack_filter(filter_var($_POST['landen'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
        // Protect and validate gerecht against hacking
        $gerechtKeuze = hack_filter(filter_var($_POST['gerechten'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $landKeuze, $gerechtKeuze);
        // If statement is not executed then give an error message.

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo 'Failed to execute the query: ' . $stmt->error . ' in query: ' . $queryInsert;
        }
        $stmt->close();
      }
      // Else give an error message
      else {
         echo 'Something went wrong in the query: ' . $mysqli->error;
      }
}

// Function to controle the insert values from POST landen and POST gerechten
function hack_filter($dataHackControl) {
    $dataHackControl = trim($dataHackControl); // Strip whitespaces
    $dataHackControl = stripslashes($dataHackControl); // Strip off backslashes
    $dataHackControl = htmlspecialchars($dataHackControl); // Convert special characters to HTML entities
    return $dataHackControl;
}
?>
```

I solved one problem with the code below. I added it in the code above after bind_param():

```
<?php 
if ($landKeuze == 0 || $landKeuze > 5 || $gerechtKeuze == 0 || $gerechtKeuze > 15) {
    echo '<script>alert("Deze keuze bestaat niet. Kies opnieuw!");location.replace("keuze.php")</script>';
    $landKeuze = null;
    $gerechtKeuze = null;
} 
?>
```

**But the problem is:**
It's still possible to get wrong dishes coupled with the chosen country in the source code (F12).

For example:
Country(id) 1 is China with dish(id) 1 Babi Pangang,
Country(id) 2 is Sri Lanka with dish(id) 4 Chicken curry.

When I choose China with Babi Pangang (1, 1) and I change the dish value/id in 4 (Chicken curry) then I get (1, 4) in the table but that's not allowed.

How can I prevent that without an if-else if contruction?

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: You have to restrict user input to what is possible. If an impossible input occurs you generate an nice error message.

Comment: i think you should mention your problem in an appropriate way. this is to much code. precised the problem

Comment: @BilalAhmed I hope it is more readable now. Otherwise let met know.

Comment: It's my first question here, so any tip to improve me here at Stackoverflow is welcome.